# Retriving nested data from Dynamo with boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am been looking for the this solution around internet but, can not find an answer.

I am trying to query dynamo using boto3 query(), just to avoid retrieving  the whole table object I would like, to get the a dictioanry inside a dictionay inside a dictionary like this:

```
{
"attr1" : "anything",
"atrr2" : {
            "somekey" : { obj1 : {},
                          obj2 : {}

                        }
}

}
```

SO what I like to query is the full object that is the value of somekey with boto3 dynamodb.query().

How ever i an not able to filter the query so that i can get that object, was trying something like:

```
query(KeyConditionExpression=Key('atrr1').eq('anything'), FilterExpression=Attr('attr2.stacks').eq('obj1'))
```

WHat would be the right query?

Comment: There is an example at http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/dynamodb.html that shows scans of nested attributes: FilterExpression=Attr('address.state').eq('CA')

Comment: Yup! Thanks, that actually worked, but I still trying to grab just obj2 or obj1, with this query, it return the whole attr2 obj.